# Centered div with position:absolute has offset for Android devices when content is larger than viewport

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Issue shows up on Android browsers when the following are on a page:

- A `div` element with a size larger than the device's viewport. (I used 1200px.)
- One or more other `div` elements with *either* `left:0; right:0; margin:auto;` or `left:50%; margin-left:-100px` style centering.

The issue is that the "centered" `div` elements actually aren't. They have an **offset to the left** (or top if centering vertically). The problem shows up on Android devices in both Chrome and Dolphin (WebKit). It does not show up on desktops (tested Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and IE).

Here is some example CSS:

```
body{ margin:0; padding:0; }
.wide-element {
    position:absolute;
    height:800px; width:1200px;
    left:50%; margin-left:-600px;
    background:url(1200px-wide.png);
}
.fixed-1, .fixed-2, .absolute-1, .absolute-2 { height:200px; width:200px; }
.fixed-1 {
    position:fixed; margin:auto;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}
.fixed-2 {
    position:fixed; margin:-105px 0 0 -105px;
    left:50%; top:50%; 
    border:5px solid blue;
}
.absolute-1 {
    position:absolute; margin:auto;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
.absolute-2{
    position:absolute; margin:-105px 0 0 -105px;
    left:50%; top:50%;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wide-element"></div>
    <div class="fixed-1"></div>
    <div class="fixed-2"></div>
    <div class="absolute-1"></div>
    <div class="absolute-2"></div>
</body>
```

I added the `position:fixed` pair to contrast with the `position:absolute` pair. As you can see in the following screenshot, the `fixed` divs are both at the actual center of the screen, while the `absolute` divs are slightly up and to the left of the center of the layout. The most problematic part is that **this offset causes elements on the left side of the screen to be cut off, and unreachable**.

[image]

I'd like to know why (exactly) is this happening (and why only on mobile devices), but the real question is:

How can I reliably center a `div` element that might be larger than the viewport, without Android devices making parts of the page unreachable?

Comment: this is the main trouble with this oldish way to center element. you could set a min-height/width to body to equal size of your element to force scrolling on body and keep element at the most offset to 0 0 (top,left), else you have other methods like inline-block , display table/table-cell and now dislay flex as well, all keeping element in the flow of their container and screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a provisional answer to my own question.

Adding a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">` line to the `head` section seems to force the browser to set the viewport to the specified size. However, since this isn't a true fix, and others may need a more flexible solution, I'm leaving it open for a more complete answer.